# Blank 1st page when converting HTML to PDF using nreco.generated

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, vb.net, vs-web-site-project

Nreco converted my html code to pdf successfully but It created blank page  at first page of pdf with number 5 for A4 page size and 104 for letter size.

I searched about this problem and test all below style but do not work.

```
page-break-before:avoid;
page-break-after:avoid;
page-break-inside :avoid;



Dim sw As New StringWriter()
Dim htw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
Panel1.RenderControl(htw)
Dim Converter As HtmlToPdfConverter = New HtmlToPdfConverter()
Dim htmlContent As String = sw.ToString()
Dim pdf As Byte() = Converter.GeneratePdf(sw.ToString(),PdfSharp.PageSize.Letter)
Response.Charset = "utf-8"
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + "test.pdf")
Response.Buffer = True
Response.BinaryWrite(pdf)
Response.Flush()
Response.Clear()
Response.End()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use NReco.PdfGenerator nuget package then the following line is wrong:

```
Dim pdf As Byte() = Converter.GeneratePdf(sw.ToString(),PdfSharp.PageSize.Letter)
```

because t[his overload of GeneratePdf method](https://www.nrecosite.com/doc/NReco.PdfGenerator/?topic=html/M_NReco_PdfGenerator_HtmlToPdfConverter_GeneratePdf_1.htm) expects 2 arguments: first string one is main HTML content (required) and second string is for 'cover' page (special content for the first page) which is optional (can be null).

To set output page size you can set [HtmlToPdfConverter.Size property](https://www.nrecosite.com/doc/NReco.PdfGenerator/?topic=html/P_NReco_PdfGenerator_HtmlToPdfConverter_Size.htm):

```
Converter.Size = PageSize.Letter;
```